# Panel data sql moving average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data:

| id | Date | postal code | Type | price | AVG price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | flat | 100 |  |
| 1046 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | flat | 125 |  |
| 1047 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | flat | 150 |  |
| 1048 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | house | 200 |  |
| 1049 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | house | 300 |  |
| 1050 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | house | 400 |  |
| 1051 | 01/01/2020 | 75012 | ..... | ..... |  |

I would like a moving average on 3 or more periods, I get something like that:

| id | Date | postal code | Type | price | AVG price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | flat | 100 | 100 |
| 1046 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | flat | 125 | 112,5 |
| 1047 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | flat | 150 | 125 |
| 1048 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | house | 200 | **158,33** |
| 1049 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | house | 300 | **216,66** |
| 1050 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | house | 400 | 300 |
| 1051 | 01/01/2020 | 75012 | ..... | ..... |  |

But I would like it gives me something which begin again when the type and the price change:

| id | Date | postal code | Type | price | AVG price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | flat | 100 | 100 |
| 1046 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | flat | 125 | 112,5 |
| 1047 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | flat | 150 | 125 |
| 1048 | 01/01/2020 | 75011 | house | 200 | **200** |
| 1049 | 01/02/2020 | 75011 | house | 300 | **250** |
| 1050 | 01/03/2020 | 75011 | house | 400 | 300 |
| 1051 | 01/01/2020 | 75012 | ..... | ..... |  |

For now my request is like

```
select ID, date, postal_code, type, price, 
      AVG(price) OVER(ORDER by "date"::date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)AS avg_price 
from x
```

Comment: Looks like a kind of Gaps and Islands Problem. A lot of solutions could be found here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
SELECT ID, date, postal_code, type, price, 
       avg(price) OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY "date"::date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  FROM x
```